# cross browser caching script files

Tags: java, javascript, internet-explorer, caching, servlets

I want a single javascript file to be cached for 1 hr and use the below code to achieve that. For some reason(may be because that js file is loaded asynchronously) the functions in that js file do not execute in IE8 when the js file is in cache. So I want to cache the js file in all the browsers except IE. Can I set a header so that the js file does not cache only for IE browsers?

```
try { 

       response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age="+AIMConstants.CACHE_CONTROL_TIME_PERIOD); 

      } catch (Exception e) { 
       logger.info("Error in setting the cache control"); 
       e.printStackTrace(); 
      }
```

Note: The js file is being loaded multiple times on the page via getScript call. So if I apply a conditional logic only for IE to fetch that js file by appending a variable to the file, the file may be loaded multiple times which is why I'm not adding a random variable on the client side to fetch a new copy of the javascript file. I want to resolve this using the header directives. Any other solution involving javascript is also welcome.

UPDATE: I added Vary:* to prevent caching of the js file and when I do that all the browsers take a new copy of js file. I want only IE to retrieve a new copy of js file everytime. All other browsers can cache the js file.

Comment: Add the same "random" variable to all the GetScript calls on the page. Then it will cache within the page but not across page loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works retrieves a fresh copy from the server everytime only for IE browser.

```
var jsCache = true;
        if($.browser.msie){
            jsCache = false;
        }
            if(!initialized){

                $.getScript('thatjsfileurl', function() { 
                 $("#welcome").pluginInit({
                    start:'newPage'
                 });  
                 initialized = true;
                },jsCache);
            }
```